# java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin"'s signer information does not match signer information

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

my code:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(11);
parser.setUnitName("D:\\code\\sscs\\filecenter_service\\src");
parser.setEnvironment(null, null, null, false);
parser.setSource("code".toCharArray());
parser.setResolveBindings(false);
parser.setBindingsRecovery(false);
parser.setStatementsRecovery(false);
parser.setKind(8);
Map<String, String> options = JavaCore.getOptions();
options.put("org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source", "1.8");
options.put("org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance", "1.8");
parser.setCompilerOptions(options);
```

Run the results：

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin"'s signer     information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:1150)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:905)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1014)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at             java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
```

at        java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoad        er.java:698)
at         java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621    )
at     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
at     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
at     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoad    er.java:698)
at     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621    )
at     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
at     java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.initializeDefaults(ASTParser.java:293)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.(ASTParser.java:243)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.newParser(ASTParser.java:134)
at     com.ctcc.misas.analysis.service.fileaya.UnionServiceTest.doAnalyse(UnionServiceTest.java:50)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at     java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java    :62)
at     java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorI    mpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at     org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at     org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(I    nvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at     org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at     org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension    .java:140)
at     org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.jav    a:84)
at     org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoid    Method$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at     org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:    105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(    InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestM    ethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
at     org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(Node    TestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at